# Why nothing happened after selecting "Convert operators to Unicode" in Comma?

Tags: unicode, raku, commaide

After I select "Convert operators to Unicode" in [Comma](https://commaide.com), and enter the following code:

```
my @array = 1,3,5,7,9;
say @array >>+>> 3;
```

`>>+>>` should be converted to `»+»`, but nothing happend.

This is the version of Comma:

Comma 2021.01(Community Edition)
Build #CT-202.6948.81, build on January 29, 2021

Runtime version: 1.8.0_261-bb12 x86_64
VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation.

[image: Convert operators to Unicode]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the "Scheme:" combobox you see the "Default (IDE)" value, which means you are currently editing default setting scheme for the IDE. However, it is an IntelliJ thing that this scheme does not automatically equal to your current project settings (which sometimes surprises users).

If you switch it to "Project (Project)" it is highly likely the settings will differ (no Unicode editing, as it is turned off by default), so you enable it for the current project scheme and it should work out, otherwise please report, that would most likely be a bug.

Comment: Thank you! It works after I switch it to "Project (Project)